# angular mat-table: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

While trying to create a mat-table in angular, I'm receiving the error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` from using the following code. can anyone see where I'm going wrong:
my API is working, I just can't seem to bind it to the data source for some reason.

user.service.ts:

```
getUsers() {
  this.http
    .get<{ message: string; users: any }>("http://3.130..???/api/users")
    .pipe(
      map(employeeData => {
        return employeeData.users.map(user => {
          return {
            id: user._id,
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            userType: user.userType,
          };
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe(transformedUsers => {
      this.users = transformedUsers;
      this.usersUpdated.next([...this.users]);
    });
}

getUserUpdateListener() {
  return this.usersUpdated.asObservable();
}
```

userList.component.ts:

```
export class UserListComponent {
  Page = "User Table"
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  users: User[] = [];
  private usersSub: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["id", "email", "password"];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<User>;

  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.usersService.getUsers();
    this.usersSub = this.usersService.getUserUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.users);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        console.log(this.dataSource)
        console.log(this.users)
      });
  }
```

userList.component.html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z3">

    <!-- id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> id </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee"> {{employee.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- email Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> email </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee"> {{employee.email}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- password Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="password">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> password </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let employee"> {{employee.password}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Log `employeeData` to the console before calling `employeeData.users.map(...)` -- the error message is suggesting that `employeeData` does not have a field called `users`.

Comment: Either the type doesn't have a users property or your api route might be incorrect, either way check the network tab in of your browser dev tools, see if the request is sucessful or if it is, check the structure of the inbound payload and see if it matches the type you defined.